# Spring Boot Maven plugin - How do I build a zip file with Java jar file and script to run it?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a simple Spring Boot Java application and am building it using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` **repackage** goal.

I want to be able to package up the application, its dependencies and a script file that will be used to run the Java application, into a zip file. The script will be a Windows batch (.bat) script.

Does the plugin support this? I briefly looked at the plugin documentation, but couldn't find anything.

If this plugin is not able to do this, or if there is a better alternative, please let me know. I've worked with Maven in the past, but am a little rusty.

Comment: The spring boot maven plugin is not capable of doing that. But you can combine and using the maven-assembly-plugin to create the zip archive and creating a script like `start.cmd` (I would suggest to use `.cmd` instead `.bat`)...

Comment: OK, yes I've used the assembly plugin before. Took a little bit to figure it out, but got it to work. Could you post your suggestion as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [spring-boot-maven-plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/) is not capable of doing that.

But you can combine and using the [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to create the zip archive and creating a script like `start.cmd` (I would suggest to use `.cmd` instead `.bat`)